# Is There Any Way To Enable Scrollbar for Android Recyclerview Below LOLLIPOP

Tags: scrollbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, material-design

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

The Above XML Code  Enables Scrollbar for RecyclerView on LOLLIPOP and above version  , but on version below LOLLIPOP It's not enabling , any Tip and suggestion would be a great help thanks